# What do the Long vowel rule and Palatalized long vowel rule represent?

Tags: orthography, classical-japanese

In relation to the Classical Japanese orthography what are the **Long vowel (長音 Chōon) rule** and the **Palatalized long vowel (開拗長音 Kaiyōchōon) rule**?

What would be some examples of them?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "rule" here; can you write a bit more on where did you find this concept? It *sounds* like this may refer to how e.g. だう in the old *kana* orthography is now read as *dō* (*-au*  changed to a long vowel, i.e. diphthong coalescence), and how e.g. きやう in the old *kana* orthography is now read as *kyō* (palatalized long vowel).

Comment: As I remember, 開拗長音 corresponds to "palatalized long _open_ vowel", doesn't it?

Comment: ＠leoboiko They were mentioned in an article in Wikipedia : (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Japanese_language#Long_vowel_.28.E9.95.B7.E9.9F.B3_Ch.C5.8Don.29_rule)  I also thought they had something to do with the だう case you mentioned, (the second case seems to be the Y-row (ヤ行 Ya-gyō) rule, as they refer to it), but I couldn't find anything about them at all.

Comment: @broccoliforest according to [wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8B%97%E9%9F%B3) at least, Japanese 開拗音 correspond to /j/-palatalization (kya/kyu/kyo), being opposed to 合拗音/円唇化 which is labialization (kwa/gwa). So the qualifier 開 doesn't seem to refer to open/close vowels in this case.

Comment: Wow, that English Wikipedia article is a mess @user18849. I suggest you use Japanese sources on 旧仮名遣い/歴史的仮名遣い (like [this](http://www5a.biglobe.ne.jp/accent/kana/kana0.htm)), or check out Wixted's *Handbook to Classical Japanese* or Shirane's *Classical Japanese*. The English Wikipedia article makes it seem a lot more complex than it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「古典的仮名遣い」あるいは「歴史的仮名遣い」と言われるものの質問と判断しました。
百人一首など日本語の古典や和歌を読むときに必要ですね。
*I judged it as a question of what is said to be "classical kana orthography" or "historical kana orthography"*.
*It is necessary when reading Japanese classics and Japanese poetry such as **Hyakunin Isshu***.

文献としては、
読み物として[ここ](https://sfmurasamekai.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/%E5%8F%A4%E5%85%B8%E7%9A%84%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E9%81%A3%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E6%96%B9/)にありますが、ご希望の[ルール](http://www.geocities.jp/nm3032nakatsu/koten/kt01.html)については、こちらの方がまとまっていると思います。
*As a reference, [here](https://sfmurasamekai.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/%E5%8F%A4%E5%85%B8%E7%9A%84%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E9%81%A3%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E6%96%B9/) is one as a reading material, but I think [this one](http://www.geocities.jp/nm3032nakatsu/koten/kt01.html) is gathered neatly as the rule of your choice*.

ルールを抜き出すと次のようになります。
*I extracted the rule.
It becomes as follows*:

> **歴史的仮名遣い** → **現代仮名遣い**　　 **例**
> **Historical kana** → **Modern kana**　**Example**
> **orthography**　　　**orthography**
>
> - 「ぢ」→「じ」　　　　　はぢ→はじ　恥
> - 「づ」→「ず」　　　　　めづらし→めずらし　珍し
> - 「む」→「ん｣　　　　　 かむなづき→かんなづき　神無月
> - 「ゐ」→「い」　　　　　ゐなか→いなか　田舎
> - 「ゑ」→「え」　　　　　こゑ→こえ　声
> - 「を」→「お」　　　　　をかし→おかし　可笑し
> - 「くわ」→「か」　　　　くゎがく→かがく　科学
> - 「ぐわ」→「が」　　　　ぐゎん→がん　雁
> - 語頭以外のハ行→ワ行　　つはもの→つわもの 強者、いふ→いう 言う、にほひ→におい 匂い
> - ｢ア段の音＋う（ふ）｣→｢オ段＋う｣  かうべ→こうべ　首/頭
> - ｢イ段の音＋う（ふ）｣→｢イ段＋ゅう｣　きふ→きゅう　急
> - ｢エ段の音＋う（ふ）｣→｢イ段＋ょう｣　てふてふ→ちょうちょう 蝶々、けふ→きょう 今日

Comment: `pseudonym` は、「平仮名」などの「[仮名]{かな}」という意味ではなく、「[仮名]{かめい}」「偽名」という意味の語ですよ。